# How to deploy a remote production server using Jenkins?

Tags: django, jenkins, continuous-integration

We currently have our Dev server and Jenkins server on the same Cloud instance1.

> 1. OS user: djDev
> 2. Jenkins install owner: jenkins

We are able to deploy our Django application build on this same instance1 using Jenkins and application is accessible fine but the files are deployed in

> /var/lib/jenkins

folder. This is because Jenkins configuration is pointing to

> /var/lib/jenkins

Is this possible to deploy the application in OS user folder, like

> /home/djDev/djApp

While we try to modify the above folders and keep this instance1 for both Dev and Jenkins server, we need to deploy a production server on a remote cloud instance2 and deploy the application in a desired OS user´s using the same Jenkins server.

> (ex: user: djProd and /home/djProd/djApp)

Our plan is to deploy the Production server as soon as automated tests are passed on Dev. server. Our repository is in Github.

Please let me if there is any recommended steps to achieve the above deployment especially for Django application and also when users are different on each instance?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this blog post:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deploying-application-jenkins-cicd-pipeline-using-master-neel-soni/.
I followed the steps to add an agent for my production server node. The production server userś directory is taken now during deployment

> [Pipeline] node Running on ProdServer in
> /home/djprod/workspace/prod-djApp

but I get this permission error:

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no djprod@xx.xxx.xxx.xx uptime && ls -l

Bad owner or permissions on /home/djprod/.ssh/config

and config file has this permission on the production server:

> -rw-rw-r-- 1 djprod djprod   63 Dec 29 04:21 config

Iḿ not sure whether it is safe to change permissions to 600 on this file?